# android-async-http difference between connecation timeout and response time out

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-networking, android-json, android-async-http

What is connection timeout and what is response time out.

when i am try to set Maximum try and timeout using setMaxRetriesAndTimeout()
then connection retrieves after twice time , I use AsyncHttpClient (library 1.4.9 API) library for parse and process json

Comment: I think this link will be help you understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069382/what-is-the-difference-between-connection-and-read-timeout-for-sockets

Comment: no , I want to ask why retry get twice time out time