# Spring 5 webflux inter-dependent webclient calls are not getting timeout

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have two interdependent webclient calls to different api's , when the first webclient call response is delayed then readtimeout excpetion is coming . but whenever the first call is success and the second call response is delayed then it is waiting for response indefinitely.

i tried creating seperate instances of webclient for each call . still issue persists.

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
            .tcpConfiguration(client ->

                    client.doOnConnected(conn -> conn
                            .addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(10))
                            .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(10))));


    return WebClient.builder().baseUrl(url).clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
            .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.withDefaults())
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
            .filter(ExchangeFilterFunctions
                    .basicAuthentication(", "))
            .build();
```

Two subsequent calls are below where , when the second call is delayed response then the readtimeout exception is not thrown

```
request = request.flatMap(req ->
                tempService.getId(loggedInUser, token)
      .map(response -> {
                            req.setRetrieveClientIdentifier(response.getId());
                            return seRequest;
                        }))

                .zipWhen(request -> tempService.getIdFor(request.getIdentifier(), accountToken)).map(tuple -> {

                    tuple.getT1().setID(tuple.getT2().getId());
                    return tuple.getT1();
                });
```

Comment: are you sure its a read timeout issue and not a connection timeout issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069382/what-is-the-difference-between-connection-and-read-timeout-for-sockets try configuring the the connection timeout. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-builder-reactor-timeout

Comment: yes i added but still same , My only question  irrespective any number of subsequent calls  ,the timeout behaviour should work . but in my case for the second subsequent call its not working .
    TcpClient tcpClient = TcpClient.create()
                .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, connectTimeoutMills)
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_TIMEOUT, connectTimeoutMills)
                .doOnConnected(connection ->
                        connection.addHandlerLast(new